# Query UUID with BigQuery

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery, uuid

I need to make a query on CloudSQL (PostgreSQL). One of the columns - `id` - has UUID values. BigQuery does not accept this type of data, and therefore reports this error:

```
Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY PostgreSQL type UUID in column id is not supported in BigQuery. You can cast it to a supported type by PostgreSQL CAST () function. at [1:15]
```

However, I cannot transform the UUID type into a string (for example) to complete the suggestion that the error gives, which is to use CAST.

Here's the way I'm trying:

```
SELECT CAST (id as STRING) FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY (" projects / xxx-sandbox / locations / us / connections / CloudSQL "," SELECT * FROM transactions; ");
```

But it doesn't work, because from what I understand, the UUID is a binary number.

What would be the best way to make this transformation for this query?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not in English.

Comment: I edited for English.
Sorry about that, thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about CloudSQL, but can you do this in your final statement?  `SELECT id::varchar FROM transactions;`

Comment: Looks like you are doing the `CAST` too late in the process. I'm guessing it needs to be in the `SELECT * FROM transactions;` portion.

Comment: In this case, it responds with this error:

Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY
Failed to get query schema from PostgreSQL server, prepare statement failed. Error: ERROR:  type "string" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT CAST(id as STRING) FROM coupons_redeemed; /* Federate...

Comment: You probably should try casting stuff explicitly in your postgres query (before bigquery picks it up). So, the `SELECT * FROM transactions;` query should be `SELECT cast(id as varchar) as id, cast(column_1 as something), column_2, .. from transactions;`.

Comment: Tks Khan, this is a soluction:

SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("production.US.CloudSQL","SELECT cast(id as varchar) as id FROM transactions;");

with your tip I managed to evolve.

Comment: There is no data type `string`. If this is PostgreSQL, use `text` instead.

Comment: Please don't add `[SOLVED]` and similar expressions to your question. If you solved your problem, you can post an answer in the answers section below. The question should stay purely a question

Answer (score 1):

Here is a page that shows which type can be casted into which:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/federated_query_functions#postgressql_mapping

For UUID, think you will have to do the cast within the query (postgres) that fetches the data. As an example, I tried the following and it worked:

```
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("projects/xxxxxxx/locations/us-central1/connections/xxxxxx", "SELECT CAST(myuuid AS TEXT) FROM mytable;");
```